# Suggest some of the best free flowchart and notes taking web application for the purpose of instant access and quick drafting?

Tags: web-applications, drawing, flowchart

I have tried many online websites like lucid.app, draw.io. Lucid app is great but it is paid. Draw io is not working very dynamically for the rapid draft works and the flowchart functioning is a bit messy. Can i have some of the free alternatives.

I'm expecting a free website with excellent flowchart making experience and note taking experience.

Comment: Do you use a cloud storage service such as MEGA, Sync.COM, Dropbox, OneDrive, etc... where you can access files on many computers?  Are you wanting to work on desktop computers? The best I've found for this is [VUE](https://vue.tufts.edu/) from Tufts university.  It's not perfect, has a minor quirk or two, and I don't believe it is currently under development, but its and excellent product!  Has a lot of functionality that most people probably never take the time to explorer.  I love how easy it is to adjust the position of nodes using ALT+Keys.  Medium learning curve.